# Why SendMessage Not Passing

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I want to pass object of below class to another application(C#)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public class xx
    {
        public int cursorPos { get; set; }
        public int selectionLength { get; set; }
    }
```

How I send;

```
private void btnSend_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {          
            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

            foreach ( Process proc in Process.GetProcesses() )
            {
                if ( proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("RedBrowser.Net") )
                {
                    handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
                }
            }

            if ( handle != IntPtr.Zero )
            {

                xx cs = new xx();
                cs.selectionLength = 10;

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(cs, Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(cs)), false);

                Win32.CopyDataStruct cds = new Win32.CopyDataStruct();
                cds.lpData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cs));
                cds.cbData = Marshal.SizeOf(cs);    
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(cds, Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(cds)), false);
                Win32.SendMessage(handle, Win32.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
            }            
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not send");
        }
```

How I receive;

```
protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
        {
            switch ( m.Msg )
            {
                case Win32.WM_COPYDATA:

                    Win32.CopyDataStruct cds = (Win32.CopyDataStruct)m.GetLParam(typeof(Win32.CopyDataStruct));

                    // If the size matches
                    if ( cds.cbData == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(xx)) )
                    {
                        xx myStruct = (xx)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cds.lpData, typeof(xx));
                        MessageBox.Show(myStruct.selectionLength.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // let the base class deal with it
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

At first run I get some garbage value () and second, third,.. I get nothing (0)

What is wrong in here..?

Comment: Not too familiar with this but after you've allocated memory for `lpData` in your sending code, I can't see anything that looks like it's meant to copy `cs` into that allocated memory.

Comment: It is not cs, it is cds

Comment: `cds` is the `CopyDataStruct`. I'd assumed that the actual data you wanted to pass across was the `xx` instance referenced as `cs`, and to which you assigned the `selectionLength` of 10.

Comment: Also, `Marshal.StructureToPtr` copies data into the memory pointed to by the `ptr` parameter that you pass - but you're not keeping copies of those pointers anywhere, so you're effectively discarding the results (and leaking memory).

Comment: @Buddhi Regarding the bounty, what are you looking for?

Comment: Seeing the hoops C# programs have to jump through to do stuff like this makes me wonder what the point of it is. Have you considered trying C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that whilst you allocate the pointer `cds.lpData`, you do not actually write anything to the block of memory that `cds.lpData` points to. So its contents are not initialised and could contain anything.

I think the structure would be much better declared as a simple structure like this:

```
public struct xx
{
    public int cursorPos;
    public int selectionLength;
}
```

I'd then use this code to send:

```
xx cs;
cs.cursorPos = 0;
cs.selectionLength = 10;
cds.cbData = Marshal.SizeOf(cs);    
cds.lpData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cs));
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(cs, cds.lpData, false);
    Win32.SendMessage(handle, Win32.WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cds.lpData);
}
```

Comment: Your snippet is very troublesome, xx is a struct.  So calling GCHandle.Alloc() *boxes* the struct value.  The returned pointer points to the boxed value, it is not layout-compatible with the unmanaged struct.  Marshal.StructureToPtr() is a hard requirement, the OP's approach is the correct one.

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm, boxing, don't know about that. Is it better now? Thanks a lot for your ongoing teaching!